# Remove word values from the output of UNIQUE(SourceArray) in a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to list all the "other" options of a Google form. As such, I am using `UNIQUE` to list all results from a row so:

```
=UNIQUE('Form Responses'!S2:S)
```

I would the want to exclude the following from my unique query or prevent Unique form listing the following: `No explanation/don’t know`, `to far`, `Too costly`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the unwanted results by using the `FILTER` function:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A; A1:A <> "No explanation/don't know"; A1:A <> "To far"; A1:A <> "Too costly"))
```

Check out [this example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avea1NXBTibYdFh1NFBqMkEtRExrVmt1LXY0OEVBbVE&usp=sharing).